# How do I prove that the addition of the measures of two sets is the measure of their union?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How do I prove that if $(X, M, \mu)$ is a measure space and $A$, $B$ are elements of $M$, 
$μ(A∪B) +  μ(A∩B) = μA+μB$?

Comment: You want to write $A\cup B$ as a union of disjoint sets, so you can use the additivity of $\mu$.

Comment: The union simplifies to $\mu(A)+\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B)$

Comment: Write down just $A \cup B = (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A) \cup (B\cap A)$ as a disjoint union, and do the same with $A$ and $B$. Then apply additivity of the measure.